# How are IEEE-754 single and double precision formats determined?

Tags: precision, ieee-754

I'm interested in how these are determined:

1. Single precision has: 8 bits for e and rest (23 bits) are mantissa
2. Double precision: 11 bits for e and rest (52 bits) are mantissa
   ofc there is 1 bit for sign.

So how is it determined what number of bits is for mantissa, and what number of bits is for e. I guess this is noob question, but I would like to know the answer.

Comment: Because it says here: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=4610933

Comment: It is arbitrary. One day a group of engineers got together and decided on how best to represent floating point numbers. They came up with this format and hardware and software vendors went with it.

Comment: Excellent question actually. There are quite natural reasons for the total of 32 and 64 bits, because that was even 20 years ago what we expected to be a "natural" size for many years to come. For the distribution (8 + 23 or 11 + 52), the alternatives would have been for example 7+24 or 9+22. You win some precision and lose some range or the other way round. Someone just had to decide what the optimal point is.

Comment: @jliv902 For a much more accurate description of how things happened, see http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html . Unfortunately that essay does not touches on the trade-offs in the attribution of bits to different formats, but these were of course also carefully weighted.

Comment: [Why did IEEE 754 choose to allocate 23 bits to the manitssa and not 22 or 24 (etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51777010/995714), [What is the rationale for exponent and mantissa sizes in IEEE floating point standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4397081/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the rationale for exponent and mantissa sizes in IEEE floating point standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397081/what-is-the-rationale-for-exponent-and-mantissa-sizes-in-ieee-floating-point-sta)

Answer (score 4):

If you develop a format for your own then you can decide how many bits for the exponent and mantissa depending on that you need more precision or a larger range. Since IEEE-754 is designed for general use, they must choose what's better in most situations

Before IEEE-754 there were lots of floating-point formats with different pros and cons, some of those are from DEC's. Initially DEC created the 32-bit F and 64-bit D formats for their VAX system, both have 8 bits for the exponent in order to represent all important physical constants, including the Plank constant (6.626070040 × 10<sup>-34</sup>) and the Avogadro constant (6.022140857 × 10<sup>23</sup>). But they quickly realized that the number is quite limited and overflow/underflow happen every now and then so they have to add 3 more bits to the exponent to create a new 64-bit G format. When Dr. Kahan wrote the IEEE-754 draft he [*"suggested that DEC VAX's floating-point be copied because it was very good for its time"*](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/ieee754status/754story.html) and that's why IEEE-754 single and double precision have 8 and 11 bits in the exponent part respectively

Another rationale for the 64-bit format is to allow repeated multiplication without overflow

> For the 64-bit format, the main consideration was range; as a minimum, the desire was that the product of any two 32-bit numbers should not overflow the 64-bit format. The final choice of exponent range provides that a product of eight 32-bit terms cannot overflow the 64-bit format — a possible boon to users of optimizing compilers which reorder the sequence of arithmetic operations from that specified by the careful programmer.
>
> ["A Proposed Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic"](https://www.computer.org/csdl/mags/co/1981/03/01667284.pdf), David Stephenson, IEEE Computer, Vol. 14, No. 3, March 1981, pp. 51-62

It's the same reason that various DSPs have a wider accumulator register, usually 40-bit to allow adding 32-bit values 256 times without overflow

In fact nowadays the rule for IEEE-754 interchange format the size for the exponent is *round(4 log<sub>2</sub>(k)) − 13* bits so every time we double the width of the type, the exponent will be have ~4 more bits which allows for 16 multiplications of the narrower type without overflow

In the 16-bit half-float format, as the range would be too narrow and the maximum value is even much smaller than the maximum 16-bit int value if using only 4 bits for the exponent, they use 5 bits instead. Half-floats are mainly used in computer graphics so probably the precision of 11 bits is enough, and they need bigger exponent for wider dynamic range.

For more details read [Where did the free parameters of IEEE 754 come from?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13493/1981)